# Как задать класс?

Tags: reactjs

Использую module.css. Подскажите, как задать правильно класс dotAnimation, чтобы он был style.dotAnimation?

```
 <div className={classNames(styles.dot, styles.dotAccent, styles.two, {
        'dotAnimation' : props.animation
      })}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае стоит использовать синтаксис с квадратными скобками:

```
<div className={classNames(styles.dot, styles.dotAccent, styles.two, {
    [styles.dotAnimation]: props.animation
})}></div>
```